# How to remove some part of path in nginx reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, config, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've set frontend api url endpoint to something like this `https://host/api/login` which is `host` means nginx reverse proxy

Inside nginx config I've done something like this

```
location ~* ^/api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://somehost/$1$is_args$args;
}
```

I don't sure if it's correct but above code I want it to catch request that has `/api` at the first path and send request to `proxy_pass`'s url along with the same path. But I don't want to use `/api` for this.

**For example** if frontend has request to `/api/login` path. I want to send request to `http://somehost/login`. So how can I remove `/api` inside `nginx.conf` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://somehost/;
}
```

Comment: What about $is_args$args ? Is it matter?

Comment: The above works like you want, i.e. a request to /api/login?foo=bar is passed on as /login?foo=bar, so I wouldn't complicate it needlessly.

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't work. It still request to /api/login. I want it to be only /login.

Comment: Please check that your location is `/api/` with an ending slash.

Comment: It's work already, Thank you very much : )